# Reverse for 'detail' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['users/(?P<username>[^/]+)/$']

Tags: django, django-models, view, django-views, django-urls

I am trying to display a detail view from "Property" model. I am a bit confused so I don't know how to describe the situation, I never encountered it before.

modeles.py

```
import arrow
from django.db import models

from datetime import datetime
from autoslug import AutoSlugField
from model_utils.models import TimeStampedModel
from django.urls import reverse
from django.conf import settings


class Property(TimeStampedModel):

    title = models.CharField(max_length=2000, null=True)

    # Localizare
    residence_complex = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
    state = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
    street_number = models.IntegerField()
    zipcode = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
    building = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
    entrance = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
    apartament = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
    reper = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
    vecinatati = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)

    slug = AutoSlugField("Property Address",
                         unique=True,
                         always_update=False,
                         populate_from="title",
                         null=True)

    # Caracteristici

    class Destination(models.TextChoices):
        BIROURI = "birouri", "Birouri"
        REZIDENTIAL = "rezidentaial", "Rezidential"
        COMERCIAL = "comercial", "Comercial"

    destination = models.CharField("Destination", max_length=20,
                                   choices=Destination.choices, default=Destination.REZIDENTIAL)

    class Layout(models.TextChoices):
        DECOMANDAT = "decomandat", "Decomandat"
        SEMIDECOMANDAT = "semidecomandat", "Semidecomandat"
        NEDECOMANDAT = "nedecomandat", "Nedecomandat"
        CIRCULAR = "circular", "Circular"
        VAGON = "vagon", "Vagon"

    layout = models.CharField("Layout", max_length=20,
                              choices=Layout.choices, default=Layout.DECOMANDAT)

    floor = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=1, null=True)

    class ComfortType(models.TextChoices):
        UNU = "1", "1"
        DOI = "2", "2"
        TREI = "3", "3"
        LUX = "lux", "Lux"

    comfort_type = models.CharField("Comfort Type", max_length=20,
                                    choices=ComfortType.choices, default=ComfortType.UNU)

    class InteriorState(models.TextChoices):
        OTHER = "other", "Other"
        NECESITA_RENOVARE = "necesita-renovare", "Necesita-Renovare"
        RENOVAT = "renovat", "Renovat"
        NOU = "nou", "Nou"
        CARAMIDA = "caramida", "Caramida"

    interior_state = models.CharField("Interior State", max_length=20,
                                      choices=InteriorState.choices, default=InteriorState.OTHER)
    building_age = models.IntegerField()
    usable_sqm = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=1, null=True)
    build_sqm = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=1,  null=True)

    # Incaperi si Anexe

    rooms = models.IntegerField(null=True)
    bedrooms = models.IntegerField(null=True)
    kitchen = models.IntegerField(null=True)
    bathrooms = models.IntegerField(null=True)
    balcony = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    garage = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    # Caracteristici Imobil

    class BuildingType(models.TextChoices):
        BETON = "beton", "Beton"
        CARAMIDA = "caramida", "Caramida"
        LEMN = "lemn", "Lemn"
        BCA = "bca", "Bca"
        METAL = "metal", "Metal"
        OTHER = "other", "Other"

    building_type = models.CharField("Building Type", max_length=20,
                                     choices=BuildingType.choices, default=BuildingType.BETON)
    construction_date = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)

    class ConstructionType(models.TextChoices):
        HOUSE = "house", "House"
        MIXT_BUILDING = "mix-building", "Mix-Building"
        STUDIO_BUILDING = "studio-building", "Studio-Building"

    construction_type = models.CharField("Construction Type", max_length=20,
                                         choices=ConstructionType.choices, default=ConstructionType.MIXT_BUILDING)

    basement = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    notes = models.TextField(blank=True)
    lot_size = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=1)

    # Dotari si Utilitati

    # Pret

    buy_price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=1, null=True)
    sell_price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=1, null=True)
    rent = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=1, null=True)

    # Poze

    photo_main = models.ImageField(upload_to='photos/%Y/%m/%d/', blank=True)
    photo_1 = models.ImageField(upload_to='photos/%Y/%m/%d/', blank=True)
    photo_2 = models.ImageField(upload_to='photos/%Y/%m/%d/', blank=True)
    photo_3 = models.ImageField(upload_to='photos/%Y/%m/%d/', blank=True)
    photo_4 = models.ImageField(upload_to='photos/%Y/%m/%d/', blank=True)
    photo_5 = models.ImageField(upload_to='photos/%Y/%m/%d/', blank=True)
    photo_6 = models.ImageField(upload_to='photos/%Y/%m/%d/', blank=True)
    photo_7 = models.ImageField(upload_to='photos/%Y/%m/%d/', blank=True)
    photo_8 = models.ImageField(upload_to='photos/%Y/%m/%d/', blank=True)
    photo_9 = models.ImageField(upload_to='photos/%Y/%m/%d/', blank=True)
    photo_10 = models.ImageField(upload_to='photos/%Y/%m/%d/', blank=True)
    photo_11 = models.ImageField(upload_to='photos/%Y/%m/%d/', blank=True)
    photo_12 = models.ImageField(upload_to='photos/%Y/%m/%d/', blank=True)

    description = models.TextField(blank=True)

    # Listing Details

    is_published = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    list_date = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        """"Return absolute URL to the Contact Detail page."""
        return reverse('properties:detail', kwargs={"slug": self.slug})

    @ property
    def created_on_arrow(self):
        return arrow.get(self.created_on).humanize()

    @property
    def photoMain(self):
        try:
            url = self.photo_main.url
        except:
            url = ''
        return url
```

urls.py

```
from django.urls import path, include
from . import views
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.conf import settings

app_name = "properties"
urlpatterns = [

    # URL Pattern for the PropertyListView
    path(
        route='',
        view=views.PropertyListView.as_view(),
        name='list'
    ),

    # URL Pattern for the PropertyCreateView
    path(
        route='add/',
        view=views.PropertyCreateView.as_view(),
        name='add'
    ),

    # URL Pattern for the PropertyUpdateView
    path(
        route='<slug:slug>/update/',
        view=views.PropertyUpdateView.as_view(),
        name='update'
    ),

    # URL Pattern for the PropertyDetailView
    path(
        route='<slug:slug>/',
        view=views.PropertyDetailView.as_view(),
        name='detail'
    ),
]
urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

views.py

```
from .models import Property
from django.contrib.auth.mixins import LoginRequiredMixin
from django.views.generic import (
    ListView,
    DetailView,
    CreateView,
    UpdateView
)


class PropertyListView(ListView):
    model = Property


class PropertyDetailView(DetailView):
    model = Property


class PropertyCreateView(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    model = Property
    fields = [
        'title',
        'residence_complex',
        'state',
        'city',
        'address',
        'street_number',
        'zipcode',
        'building',
        'entrance',
        'apartament',
        'reper',
        'vecinatati',
        'destination',
        'layout',
        'floor',
        'comfort_type',
        'interior_state',
        'building_age',
        'usable_sqm',
        'build_sqm',
        'rooms',
        'bedrooms',
        'kitchen',
        'bathrooms',
        'balcony',
        'garage',
        'building_type',
        'construction_type',
        'basement',
        'notes',
        'lot_size',
        'buy_price',
        'sell_price',
        'rent',
        'photo_main',
        'photo_1',
        'photo_2',
        'photo_3',
        'photo_4',
        'photo_5',
        'photo_6',
        'photo_7',
        'photo_8',
        'photo_9',
        'photo_10',
        'photo_11',
        'photo_12',
        'description',
        'is_published',
        'list_date']

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.creator = self.request.user
        return super().form_valid(form)


class PropertyUpdateView(LoginRequiredMixin, UpdateView):
    model = Property
    fields = [
        'title',
        'residence_complex',
        'state',
        'city',
        'address',
        'street_number',
        'zipcode',
        'building',
        'entrance',
        'apartment',
        'reper',
        'vecinatati',
        'destination',
        'layout',
        'floor',
        'comfort_type',
        'interior_state',
        'building_age',
        'building_sqm',
        'usable_sqm',
        'build_sqm',
        'rooms',
        'bedrooms',
        'kitchen',
        'bathrooms',
        'balcony',
        'garage',
        'building_type',
        'construction_type',
        'basement',
        'notes',
        'lot_size',
        'buy_price',
        'sell_price',
        'rent',
        'photo_main',
        'photo_1',
        'photo_2',
        'photo_3',
        'photo_4',
        'photo_5',
        'photo_6',
        'photo_7',
        'photo_8',
        'photo_9',
        'photo_10',
        'photo_11',
        'photo_12',
        'description',
        'is_published',
        'list_date'
    ]
    action = "Update"
```

html

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block title %}Property List{% endblock title %}
{% block content %}

<div class="content-wrapper">
    <!-- Content Header (Page header) -->
    <section class="content-header">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="row mb-2">
                <div class="col-sm-6">
                    <h1>Widgets</h1>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-6">
                    <ol class="breadcrumb float-sm-right">
                        <li class="breadcrumb-item"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                        <li class="breadcrumb-item active">Widgets</li>
                    </ol>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
    </section>

    <section class="content">

        <div class="card card-solid">
            <div class="card-body pb-0">
                <div class="row d-flex align-items-stretch">

                    {% for property in property_list %}
                    <div class="col-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 d-flex align-items-stretch">
                        <div class="card bg-light">
                            <div class="card-header text-muted border-bottom-0">
                                {{ property.title }}
                            </div>
                            <div class="card-body pt-0">
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-7">
                                        <h2 class="lead"><b>{{ property.address }} {{ property.street_number }}</b></h2>
                                        <p class="text-muted text-sm"><b>No. Rooms: </b> {{ property.rooms }} </p>
                                        <p class="text-muted text-sm"><b>Rent Price: </b> {{ property.rent }} </p>
                                        <p class="text-muted text-sm"><b>Listing Date: </b> {{ property.list_date}} </p>

                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-5 text-center">
                                        <img src="{{ property.photoMain }}" alt="user-avatar" class="img img-fluid">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="card-footer">
                                <div class="text-right">
                                    <a href="#" class="btn btn-sm bg-teal">
                                        <i class="fas fa-comments"></i>
                                    </a>
                                    <a href="{% url 'properties:detail' property.slug %}"
                                        class="btn btn-sm btn-primary">
                                        <i class="fas fa-user"></i> View Details
                                    </a>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    {% endfor %}

                </div>
                <hr />
                <p>Don't see a contact listed here?</p>
                <p>
                    <a class="btn btn-primary" href="{% url 'properties:add' %}" role="button">
                        Add Property
                    </a>
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>


    </section>
</div>



{% endblock content %}
```

It is funny because I have done the exact same things for another app, and just basically copied and pasted everything, and just changed the models a bit. But this one does not wanna work.

This is the error message I get.

```
Environment:


Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/properties/piata-romana-3/

Django Version: 3.0.7
Python Version: 3.8.2
Installed Applications:
['whitenoise.runserver_nostatic',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.sites',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'django.contrib.admin',
 'django.forms',
 'crispy_forms',
 'allauth',
 'allauth.account',
 'allauth.socialaccount',
 'django_countries',
 'admin_timeline',
 'protocol.users.apps.UsersConfig',
 'protocol.contacts.apps.ContactsConfig',
 'protocol.properties.apps.PropertiesConfig',
 'protocol.leads.apps.LeadsConfig',
 'debug_toolbar',
 'django_extensions']
Installed Middleware:
['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'whitenoise.middleware.WhiteNoiseMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.locale.LocaleMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.BrokenLinkEmailsMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
 'debug_toolbar.middleware.DebugToolbarMiddleware']


Template error:
In template /home/radu/Documents/LESSON/everycheese/protocol/protocol/templates/base.html, error at line 76
   Reverse for 'detail' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['users/(?P<username>[^/]+)/$']
   66 :           <div class="image">
   67 :             <img src="../../dist/img/user2-160x160.jpg" class="img-circle elevation-2" alt="User Image">
   68 :           </div>
   69 :           <div class="info">
   70 :             <a href="#" class="d-block">Alexander Pierce</a>
   71 :           </div>
   72 :         </div>
   73 : 
   74 :         <!-- Sidebar Menu -->
   75 :         <nav class="mt-2">
   76 :            <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-sidebar flex-co lumn" data-widget="treeview" role="menu" data-accordion="false">
   77 :             <!-- Add icons to the links using the .nav-icon class
   78 :                with font-awesome or any other icon font library -->
   79 :             <li class="nav-item has-treeview">
   80 :               <a href="#" class="nav-link">
   81 :                 <i class="nav-icon fas fa-tachometer-alt"></i>
   82 :                 <p>
   83 :                   Dashboard
   84 :                   <i class="right fas fa-angle-left"></i>
   85 :                 </p>
   86 :               </a>


Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/radu/Documents/LESSON/everycheese/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/home/radu/Documents/LESSON/everycheese/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 145, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "/home/radu/Documents/LESSON/everycheese/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 143, in _get_response
    response = response.render()
  File "/home/radu/Documents/LESSON/everycheese/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/template/response.py", line 105, in render
    self.content = self.rendered_content
  File "/home/radu/Documents/LESSON/everycheese/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/template/response.py", line 83, in rendered_content
    return template.render(context, self._request)
  File "/home/radu/Documents/LESSON/everycheese/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/template/backends/django.py", line 61, in render
    return self.template.render(context)
  File "/home/radu/Documents/LESSON/everycheese/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 171, in render
    return self._render(context)
  File "/home/radu/Documents/LESSON/everycheese/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/test/utils.py", line 95, in instrumented_test_render
    return self.nodelist.render(context)
  File "/home/radu/Documents/LESSON/everycheese/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 936, in render
    bit = node.render_annotated(context)
  File "/home/radu/Documents/LESSON/everycheese/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 903, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "/home/radu/Documents/LESSON/everycheese/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py", line 150, in render
    return compiled_parent._render(context)
  File "/home/radu/Documents/LESSON/everycheese/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/test/utils.py", line 95, in instrumented_test_render
    return self.nodelist.render(context)
  File "/home/radu/Documents/LESSON/everycheese/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 936, in render
    bit = node.render_annotated(context)
  File "/home/radu/Documents/LESSON/everycheese/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 903, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "/home/radu/Documents/LESSON/everycheese/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py", line 62, in render
    result = block.nodelist.render(context)
  File "/home/radu/Documents/LESSON/everycheese/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 936, in render
    bit = node.render_annotated(context)
  File "/home/radu/Documents/LESSON/everycheese/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 903, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "/home/radu/Documents/LESSON/everycheese/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/template/defaulttags.py", line 443, in render
    url = reverse(view_name, args=args, kwargs=kwargs, current_app=current_app)
  File "/home/radu/Documents/LESSON/everycheese/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/urls/base.py", line 87, in reverse
    return iri_to_uri(resolver._reverse_with_prefix(view, prefix, *args, **kwargs))
  File "/home/radu/Documents/LESSON/everycheese/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 677, in _reverse_with_prefix
    raise NoReverseMatch(msg)

Exception Type: NoReverseMatch at /properties/piata-romana-3/
Exception Value: Reverse for 'detail' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['users/(?P<username>[^/]+)/$']
```

I would love to understand what is happening here. I am new to Django, and apparently the learning curve is much harder than expected.

Comment: I have a similar issue, with the following error message:

    `Reverse for 'detail' with arguments '('some-slug',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['users/(?P<username>[^/]+)/$']`

The intended `some-slug` is placed between parentheses for reasons beyond me.  I switch from `<slug:slug>` to `<str:slug>`, and it works.  Then switching back to `<slug:slug>` also works.  It is not placed between parentheses anymore.  Did you figure out why this happen?

Answer (score 1):

in your url try changing the `<slug:slug>` to `<str:slug>`

Comment: thank you so much!  Why is there this difference?

Comment: You're welcome!
Usually if you use SlugField in your Model you'll end up using <slug:slug> for that specific field otherwise <str:slug> witll do the trick cuz you're defining the type of the parameter expected there

Answer (score 0):

try something like:

```
<a href="{% url 'properties:detail' slug=property.slug %}"> Edit </a>
```